# how to read Date from Excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was trying to read date form an excel using this code

```
case 2:
   if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) { 
                        if ((cell.getDateCellValue()) != null) {

                            postAssumpContractPojo.setAssumptionDate(cell.getDateCellValue());

                        }
                    }
   Break;
```

But the first Condition is getting Flase ( if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC))
And in excel date is in this format (2014-10-14)
Please Help ...

Comment: Is there another `Cell` type which states whether the cell is a date?

Comment: Make sure the cell in the excel sheet is actually of a date format and not just a text cell which includes a date like text. I suspect that is the case as a Date cell is a numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the method in `POI`'s `DateUtil` class for dealing with dates in Excelsheets, `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted()`

You can get the date as shown below.

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
{
   try {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      cellValue = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```